# Farthest distance to a solar system object that's been measured by radar?

Tags: radar, delay-doppler

Bouncing radar off of Venus' surface has yielded a rich body of data about the planet. Based on Venus' aphelion and Earth's perihelion, we know then that the answer is *at least* 38 million kilometers with a round trip of over four minutes.

Have radar reflections from Venus or any other natural solar system body been measured over distances larger than that?

Here I am primarily interested in reflections from the natural solar system body itself, so I've asked [Farthest distance to a solar system object that's been determined by spacecraft transponder?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/37753/12102) separately.

For more about Venus and radar see:

- [Why do radar maps of the surface of Venus have missing slices?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/22493/12102)
- [When did planetary scientists realize Venus' surface pressure was almost 100x that on Earth? How did they find out?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/30346/12102)
- [How was the radius of Venus measured so accurately (± 3 km) via radar in the mid 1960's, before Venera 4 and Mariner 5?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/30430/12102)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the list at [Wikipedia's article on Radio Astronomy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radar_astronomy), the furthest object that's been measured was probably Saturn's rings; Titan may have been further, depending on where in its orbit it was.  Other radar observations of note have involved making elevation maps of Mercury and Venus, and since you asked about distance, high-precision distance measurements of Mercury as a test of General Relativity.

Out beyond Saturn, it's unlikely that anything is a suitable target for radio astronomy.  The gas giants don't have well-defined radar echos, while nothing else is very big: the radar reflection from Titania would be roughly 1/150th that of Titan, that of Triton, 1/300th, and that of Pluto, 1/500th at best.

Comment: Excellent! The radar images are certainly "out there" somewhere in the literature, I'll try to get around to looking for them if nobody else does. Thanks!

Comment: fyi I've just asked [How did Arecibo detect methane lakes on Titan, and image Saturn's rings?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/33023/7982)

Comment: and [Why is Saturn invisible in this radar image of its rings?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/33060/7982)